# Disable Button on Page Load

Tags: angular

I have a web page which is loading a list of items to select from and add to a list. What I would like to do is have it so that when the user searches for an item and clicks search, any items that load and are already in the users list of selected items will have their buttons disabled. I am able to disable the buttons when the user clicks the item, however if they search for the same item, the button will be clickable again

Code for button in body.component.html:

```
<button type="submit" *ngIf="!checkNominations(mov)" (click)="nominate(mov, $event)">Nominate</button>
```

Code for checking/disabling button in body.component.ts:

```
  nominate(mov: string, event:any){
    this.nominations.push(mov);
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }

  checkNominations(mov: Object){
    return this.nominations.indexOf(mov) !== -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it in a different way, if anyone knows how to make this more efficient I would greatly appreciate it!

Code for button in body.component.html:

```
<button type="submit" *ngIf="!checkNominations(mov)" (click)="nominate(mov)">Nominate</button>
        <button type="submit" *ngIf="checkNominations(mov)" disabled="True">Nominated!</button>
```

Code for checking/disabling button in body.component.ts:

```
checkNominations(mov: Object){
    let arr = [];   
    arr.push(mov);
    var isInArray = this.nominations.find(e => e.Title === arr[0].Title) !== undefined;
    return isInArray;
  }
```